# Interfacing with Compris POS

Tags: point-of-sale, ncr

Does anyone have any data on how to interface with a Compris POS? I have a Compris POS, and I need to grab data from the database. I can't get information from NCR regarding the underlying data format, and I was wondering if anyone had reverse engineered the device, or had any documentation on the device.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of DB? Can you post the structure?

I work with a POS software company and I'm quite sure I could deconstruct it rather easily...

Comment: Sorry this took so long. They use a variety of data locations. There is a password on the database (encrypted), so that's a problem. Also, there is a tempspace of XML data.

Answer (score 0):

There are various tools such as pludump.exe, prtme.exe etc that you may already have which can provide extracts as text. These can then be imported into Excel.